# Lightning Iteration Issue

Tags: lightning, permissions

I have created a table in Salesforce Lightning that displays a table of records queried in an Apex Controller. The records are correctly queried from my client-side javascript controller, and I use component.set to store the data into a List attribute in Lightning. I use console.log to print out the data before storing it in the attribute, then I use console.log to print out the contents of the attribute right after. The console.log right after the component.set does not display anything, meaning the code is breaking at that point. The controller is called again later and when I added a console.log at the beginning to print the contents of the attribute, the first time it is empty (as expected) but the second time it actually has the contents from before, even though the code seemed to break at component.set

The weird thing is that this table works fine when I created these records in Salesforce Classic/Lightning Experience as the System Administrator. However, I have another user and when I use that user to create records the table does not work when searching for those records. The table works fine if I search for records only created by System Admin. It doesn't seem to be permissions because I have assigned the same role to that user and cloned the System Administrator profile for them. Also, I have traced the code to breaking in the area I just specified; there is no issue with the query and it appears to be storing the data in the attribute, but when it gets to the iteration it does not work. Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong? I am posting the relevant code below, all of the other fields are working fine

Thanks!

JS Controller Code:

```
if(event.getParam('action') === 'RENDER_RESULTS' && 
          event.getParam('name') === component.get("v.name")){
   var results = event.getParam('results');
   component.set('v.results', results);
}
```

Lightning Component Code:

```
<aura:attribute name="results" type="List"/>


<aura:iteration items="{!v.results}" var="record" start="{!(v.currentPage - 1)*v.numberOfItemsPerPage}"
                            end="{!(v.currentPage - 1)*v.numberOfItemsPerPage + v.numberOfItemsPerPage}">

    <c:SearchResultsSelectorTableRow item="{!record}" fieldLabelsAPIMap="{!v.fieldHeadingsAPIList}"
                                                 parentName="{!v.name}" displayRemove="{!v.displayRemove}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Could you please post the parts of the code related to your problem?

Comment: added code and clarified the issue a bit

Comment: You cloned the profile, but profils do not involve access to records. What about sharing?

Comment: Sharing is "public read/write" for internal and external users.